# file containing env vars not loading

Tags: macos, environment-variables, bash

I am trying to have my system automatically load a file containing some environment vars to use in my rails project instead of just exporting them to the shell but i just cant seem to get it working.

i'm using mac osx 10.6

these are steps i followed.

```
nano .bash_profile

export PATH=Users/Moshe/env_vars:$PATH

touch env_vars

nano env_vars

DEV_DB=TestDB
export DEV_DB

DEV_DB_HOST=12.34.56.78
export DEV_DB_HOST

exit
```

I reopen the shell and

```
printenv
```

but i don't see the vars i set

however i do see it `Users/Moshe/env_vars` in the path when i `echo $PATH`

i have tried looking at this answer but i cant seem to see what im doing wrong

[Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

Comment: remove `exit` word, then issue in the command line your script as follows: `. your_script.sh`

Comment: the `exit` is not written i just typed that into the terminal to make sure its reloaded

Comment: yes by typing that command i now see it
but i wanted this to happen automatically happen when loaded without the need to type any commands

Comment: type `set|grep DEV_DB_HOST`

Comment: either insert the code into **.bash_profile**, or store it into the specific file and call from **.bash_profile** as follows: `. your_script.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `exit` keyword. Either insert the code into **.bash_profile**, or store it into the specific file, for example **your_script.sh**, and call from **.bash_profile** as follows:

```
. your_script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables aren't read from files found on your `$PATH`; your `$PATH` is searched to find *executable files* when you type a command in the shell.

To load your variables, you'll need to "source" the file instead:

```
# .bash_profile
source /Users/Moche/env_vars
```

(Notice that you also need the initial `/` to make the filename absolute.)

Also, since you're using Ruby, you might be interested in using the [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#dotenv-). dotenv lets you specify environment variables in a `.env` file in the root of your Rails project and automatically load them on startup. This keeps the variables you need for each project close to the code and makes your project a little more portable (you can use this to deploy on a service like Heroku, for example). Just make sure you don't commit `.env` into your version control if it has any sensitive information like passwords in it!

Comment: Im gonna look into that gem

Comment: but i just tried changing from export to source with the absolute path and still not showing up

Comment: Did you re-source your `.bash_profile`? (`source ~/.bash_profile` from the terminal, or opening a new terminal window, after you save your changes.)

Comment: i used `exit` closed the terminal window and just reopened it.
do i need to use the source command?

Comment: I just used the source `~/.bash_profile` command from the terminal command line and still not showing up

Comment: Hmm. When you say "changing from export to source", did you by any chance leave the `:$PATH` bit on? (It shouldn't be there.) Do you get any errors messages when you source .bash_profile?

Comment: i changed that line to `source /Users/Moshe/env_vars` and that didn't work so i also tried to put it in quotes like so `source "/Users/Moshe/env_vars"` also no luck